# Can a JSXBIN script be called in InDesign server via SOAP?

Tags: xml, soap, jsx, indesign-server

I'm making a SOAP request to InDesign Server running on a Windows VPS. We've been running JSX scripts on this server for ages, so we know it works fine. However a third party development house has provided to us a JSXBIN file to run, and we aren't having any success in running it.

Here's our request:

```
POST / HTTP/1.1
Host: indesign-server.local:8081
Connection: Keep-Alive
User-Agent: PHP-SOAP/5.2.6-1+lenny16
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
SOAPAction: ""
Content-Length: 747

<SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
    <ns1:RunScript>
        <runScriptParameters>
            <scriptLanguage>javascript</scriptLanguage>
            <scriptFile>\\server-ip\filestore\indesign-scripts\dev-server\ResizeScript\UKtoUSsizes.jsxbin</scriptFile>
            <scriptArgs>
                <name>FOLDER</name>
                <value>\\server-ip\filestore\dev\templates\18461</value>
            </scriptArgs>
            <scriptArgs>
                <name>TEMPLATE</name>
                <value>template</value>
            </scriptArgs>
            <scriptArgs>
                <name>SCRIPT-PATH</name>
                <value>\\server-ip\filestore\indesign-scripts\dev-server</value>
            </scriptArgs>
            </runScriptParameters>
        </ns1:RunScript>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Here's the response I get:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: gSOAP/2.7
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 537
Connection: close

<SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
        <IDSP:RunScriptResponse>
            <errorNumber>48</errorNumber>
            <errorString>File or folder does not exist</errorString>
            <scriptResult/>
        </IDSP:RunScriptResponse>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

We think the paths are correct, so either the `scriptLanguage` is wrong, or maybe there is an error inside the binary. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aha, I've discovered from the Windows Event Log that this error is occurring on a particular line number, and happens just the same if we use the JSX script equivalent. It's not working yet, but at least this question is answered: yes, a JSXBIN encoded script *can* be called in InDesign Server.